# How to properly import the pipe in ionic 4 and angular 7?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4, angular-pipe

I have generated my custom 'completedOn' pipe with ionic CLI:

```
ionic g pipe completedOn
```

and it automatically generated two files.
First is **completed-on.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'completedOn'
})
export class CompletedOnPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(args);
    return value;
  }
}
```

Second is **completed-on.pipe.spec.ts**

```
import { CompletedOnPipe } from './completed-on.pipe';

describe('CompletedOnPipe', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
    const pipe = new CompletedOnPipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and **CompletedOnPipe** is imported in **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, CompletedOnPipe],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, 
FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UrlInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However, if I try to use completedOn pipe, I am getting this error:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of data | completedOn"></ion-row>
```

***Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'completedOn' could not be found***

I tried also by creating new file **main-pipe.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {CompletedOnPipe} from "./completed-on.pipe";

@NgModule({
  declarations:[CompletedOnPipe],
  imports:[CommonModule],
  exports:[CompletedOnPipe]
})

export class MainPipe{}
```

and if I import this module in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [..., MainPipe],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

there is same error.

This is my **ionic info** output

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.9.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.3
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : not available
```

Can't find a solution to properly import pipe and use it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the component where you are using this pipe lazy loaded? If so, you have to declare the pipe in the NgModule where this lazy loaded components is declared.

Comment: can you please give me an example to see how to do it

Answer (score -1):

Whe creating a pipe using the command `ionic g pipe completedOn` it will also create a module called `completedOn.module.ts`. You need to import the module in order to use the pipe.

```
import {CompletedOnPipeModule} from "./completed-on.pipe.module";
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [...],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [..., CompletedOnPipeModule],
      providers: [...],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

Comment: It automatically imported CompletedOnPipe in app.module.ts and did not created this module.

Comment: Well, i think the problem is that you can't use the pipe in *ngFor. Have you tried it with a simple `<p>{{ item | completedOn}} </p>` to check if its really the pipe that isn't working.

Comment: Don't think so, I just tried add pipe in p element and that did not worked. Same error here

Comment: Mind to share your `app.component.html` if thats the fille your working in?